# How to use ndk-stack in Android Studio?

Tags: c, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ndk-stack

I need to debug my native C code. (I'm a newbie in C and ndk). I get this error, but i don't know exactly from where the bug come from:

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x38
```

I find some [tool](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack) to do that, but the documentation is very unclear for me and I realy don't know how to use that. I tried command from documentation, but I have:

```
'$NDK' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I tried replacing `$NDK` with ndk location and `$PROJECT_PATH` with my android studio project path, but then I get:

```
C: is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How can I get the place (human readable) from where the C signal comes from using Android Studio? I would be realy grateful if somebody gave me veryy detailed step by step guide (like for idiot) with example.
I've seen many similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160680/how-to-use-ndk-stack-step-by-step) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56779125/how-do-i-use-ndk-stack-using-android-ndk-r20), but I've not found them helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Full error looks like this:

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x38
2022-04-11 14:47:00.618 28022-28022/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
2022-04-11 14:47:00.618 28022-28022/? A/DEBUG:     x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000007fcbe612e8  x2  0000000000000000  x3  0000007fcbe612f4
2022-04-11 14:47:00.618 28022-28022/? A/DEBUG:     x4  0000007fcbe5fea0  x5  000000760d208470  x6  000000760d200100  x7  0000000000000001
2022-04-11 14:47:00.618 28022-28022/? A/DEBUG:     x8  3a081cfc2b057a9c  x9  3a081cfc2b057a9c  x10 0000000000430000  x11 0000007fcbe5fe20
2022-04-11 14:47:00.618 28022-28022/? A/DEBUG:     x12 0000007fcbe5fd00  x13 0000000000000010  x14 000000760d2188fc  x15 00000000ebad6a89
2022-04-11 14:47:00.618 28022-28022/? A/DEBUG:     x16 0000007587a487e8  x17 0000007fcbe611f0  x18 0000000000000000  x19 000000778106c380
2022-04-11 14:47:00.618 28022-28022/? A/DEBUG:     x20 0000000000000000  x21 000000778106c380  x22 000000792f0f3000  x23 000000778106c430
2022-04-11 14:47:00.618 28022-28022/? A/DEBUG:     x24 00000075eb871320  x25 00000076f106d510  x26 000000792f0f3000  x27 0000000000000d89
2022-04-11 14:47:00.618 28022-28022/? A/DEBUG:     x28 0000007fcbe61200  x29 0000007fcbe61200
2022-04-11 14:47:00.618 28022-28022/? A/DEBUG:     lr  000000760d222248  sp  0000007fcbe611f0  pc  0000007587a487ec  pst 0000000060000000
2022-04-11 14:47:00.618 28022-28022/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2022-04-11 14:47:00.618 28022-28022/? A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 00000000010757ec  /data/app/~~3Zs2OavC8p7AJpYYMbAsbw==/com.fivesoft.fivesfotstreamer-4yYlj4e5I5l3j1ng0knVeQ==/base.apk!libgstreamer_android.so
2022-04-11 14:47:00.618 28022-28022/? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 0000000000222244  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+148) (BuildId: 600193f4a9fcf9ced238223aee6c1164)
2022-04-11 14:47:00.618 28022-28022/? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 0000000000218964  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 600193f4a9fcf9ced238223aee6c1164)
...
```

Comment: You should run `ndk-stack` from bash prompt, not in Windows shell. The best way to achieve this is to [install Ubuntu on your Windows machine](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-10).